# Sending long (concatenated) SMS in Japan

Tags: android, mobile

Is there anyone from Japan ? I have a question about Japan mobile network operators (Docomo, AU) and their phones: are they able to send/receive a long SMS (longer than 160 latin characters / 70 japanese characters)? or they are splitting the SMS in two fragments sent separately? 
In my app, I want to send a long SMS using SMSManager's **sendMultiPartTextMessage** and I want to know if I can use it or send multiple SMS fragments using just **sendTextMessage**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultipartTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E%29), that's how you can send multi-parts message:

```
final String phoneNumber = "1111111111";
final String message = "this is text body for multi part sms...bla bla bla...";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to send a long SMS. I'm asking if this is working for Japan mobile networks.

Comment: If your network provider uses international standards for sending sms then this should work :)

Comment: I'm developing this for someone in Japan and I don't have the option to test it right now using my network provider and the possibility to get in touch with my partner in Japan.